# MongoDB, how to find object by name in nested(?) DB imported from osm in java

Tags: java, mongodb, openstreetmap

I've read a lot of topics about using MongoDB in java programming and finding nested object in it. Unfortunetly I didn't find an answer to my question. I have a db which is imported from Open Street Map. It contains many different nodes. I've made for id full text search and it works, but I have to have another searching algorithm that finds only cities and villages. I thought that it may work when I use `findOne` method searching by "name" if user will type only one word.

Here is sample of my database, this is one record:

```
 > db.nodes.findOne() {
        "_id" : NumberLong(23658160),
        "loc" : [
                53.9475385,
                14.1787832
        ],
        "ch" : NumberLong(12846175),
        "ts" : "2012-08-24T15:07:41Z",
        "un" : "HHT",
        "ui" : NumberLong(498475),
        "v" : 9,
        "tg" : [
                [
                        "addr:city",
                        "Heringsdorf"
                ],
                [
                        "addr:housenumber",
                        "7-9"
                ],
                [
                        "addr:postcode",
                        "17424"
                ],
                [
                        "addr:street",
                        "Puschkinstraße"
                ],
                [
                        "name",
                        "Jugendherberge Heringsdorf"
                ],
                [
                        "tourism",
                        "hostel"
                ],
                [
                        "wheelchair",
                        "yes"
                ]
        ],
        "ky" : [
                "addr:city",
                "addr:housenumber",
                "addr:postcode",
                "addr:street",
                "name",
                "tourism",
                "wheelchair"
        ] }
```

Here is my code, that doesn't work.

```
if (reqTab.length == 1 && req.getHowMany() <= 1) 
{
    cmd.put("nodes.tg.name", reqTab[0]);
    DBObject resultTemp = coll.findOne(cmd);
    System.out.println(resultTemp); //here it shows null
    json = gson.toJson(resultTemp);                
}
else
{   //here it's all working!
    cmd.put("text", "nodes");
    cmd.put("search", req.getWhatToSearch());
    cmd.put("limit", req.getHowMany());
    result = db.command(cmd);
    json = gson.toJson(result);
}        
return json;
```

It always puts null, I don't know how to get into this to find records by name. 
Please, help.

Answer (score 1):

Your "name" field is inside an array inside another array - you need to get into that array to find a matching field.

In the example you've given, you need "tg.0.4.name" - because it's the name element in the 5th element of the sub-array of the first element of the initial array:

```
{
  "_id" : NumberLong(23658160),
  "loc" : [
          53.9475385,
          14.1787832
  ],
  "ch" : NumberLong(12846175),
  "ts" : "2012-08-24T15:07:41Z",
  "un" : "HHT",
  "ui" : NumberLong(498475),
  "v" : 9,
  "tg" :                        <-- Document field tg            (tg)
         [                      <-- Array.  This is element zero (tg.0)
          [                     <-- Sub array, element zero      (tg.0.0)
              "addr:city",
              "Heringsdorf"
          ],
          [                     <-- Sub array, element one       (tg.0.1)
              "addr:housenumber",
              "7-9"
          ],
          [                     <-- Sub array, element two       (tg.0.2)
              "addr:postcode",
              "17424"
          ],
          [                     <-- Sub array, element three     (tg.0.3)
              "addr:street",
              "Puschkinstraße"
          ],
          [                     <-- Sub array, element four      (tg.0.4)
              "name",           <-- Sub document, name           (tg.0.4.name)
              "Jugendherberge Heringsdorf"
          ],
  ... blah blah
}
```

Note, you do NOT need "nodes" in your path - nodes is the name of the collection, so `coll.findOne` will already be looking in the nodes collection.

```
cmd.put("tg.0.4.name", reqTab[0]);
DBObject resultTemp = coll.findOne(cmd);
```

Be aware though that this will not work if the name field is not in the fifth array. You can use [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) to check *values* in subdocuments in arrays, but not field names.  So if you want to query on field name you might find you have to re-structure your document.